# Retrieve the output of a python script with Java

Tags: java, python

I would like to run a python script that is based on speech recognition using Java and retrieve the script outputs with Java.

I managed without much trouble to call the script and run it. It works perfectly. However I do not understand why I can not recover the outputs `print` with java.

here is the **script python** :

```
import aiml
import os
import time, sys
import pyttsx
import warnings

# Initialisation of the different mode
# If no specification, Jarvis will run as a text Personnal
mode = "text"
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    if sys.argv[1] == "--voice" or sys.argv[1] == "voice":
        import speech_recognition as sr
        mode = "voice"

# Jarvis speaking part
def offline_speak(jarvis_speech):
    engine = pyttsx.init()
    engine.say(jarvis_speech)
    engine.runAndWait()

# Jarvis listenning part
def listen():
    # Jarvis listen the environnemnt to capture the voice
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Talk to JARVIS: ")
        # Jarvis is listenning
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        # Print and return what Jarvis heard
        print ("test")
        print r.recognize_google(audio, language='fr-FR')
        return r.recognize_google(audio, language='fr-FR')
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        # If Jarvis doesn't know the sentence or the word you said
        offline_speak("Je n'ai pas compris ce que vous avez dit, pouvez vous repeter s'il vous plait ?")
        print ("test")
        # Return what he heard
        return(listen())
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        # Jarvis didn't understand what you said
        print("Could not request results from Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))


# Jarvis running part
while True:
    if mode == "voice":
        response = listen()
        print ("test")
    else:
        response = raw_input("Talk to JARVIS : ")

    offline_speak(response)
    print ("test")
```

And here is my **class java** :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class PythonCaller {

    private final String pythonPrjPath;
    private final String scriptName;
    private final String args;


    public PythonCaller(String scriptName, String args) {
        this.scriptName = scriptName;
        this.pythonPrjPath = argTreatment();
        this.args = args;
    }


    public void call() throws Exception {
        try {

            List<String> commands = new LinkedList<>();
            commands.add("python");
            commands.add(pythonPrjPath);
            commands.add(args);

            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
            Process p = pb.start();

            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            // read the output from the command
            String s;
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
    }


    private String argTreatment() {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(scriptName).getFile());
        StringBuilder resPpythonPrjPath = new StringBuilder(file.getAbsolutePath());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(resPpythonPrjPath.subSequence(0,90));
        return sb.toString();
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String tabArgs = "voice";
        PythonCaller pc = new PythonCaller("listener.py", tabArgs);
        try {
            pc.call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Since he's rephrased his question in English, there's no need to downvote or voteclose

Comment: Sorry about that, i see so manyquestions in french so I forget that we have to post in english.

Comment: Your code appears to be correctly reading the output of the script.  Is it possible that you are getting something on stderr instead of stdout?  Maybe check that stream too, or you could try pb.redirectOutput(File) and pb.redirectError(File) and see if they contain anything.

Comment: Strangely, I get the result in the `getErrorStream` ... not in the `getInputSteam`... but the output of `java -version` is correct. I don't know `Process` enough to see if this is expected ... (I doubt it...)

Comment: I add to my code a bufferedReader for getErrorStream but I still get nothing on my console ...

Comment: I tried something and it's kind of strange. I defined the running part in a function. If I don't call this function, every single print I write in my script is retrieve by java and is displayed ...It's definitly the problem but I can't see why

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to solve my problem so I decided to avoid it. Instead of reading the `print`, I write the data I want to retrieve in a textfile and I read the textfile from **java**

Comment: Could you post your solution? It would help others..